# How to make a newline between the options of a JOptionPane.showOptionDialog? Java

Tags: java, joptionpane

I show a menu with many options and I have to move the page to see all the options.

I would like to make a line break so that all the options are visible without having to move the window.

Comment: Please show the code that goes along with this. Also, since this problems involves a visual bug, please show a screenshot of your application in action.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.